# How to differentiate between ios UIWebview and ios mWeb?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to know how to differentiate a user engagement on a website accessed by the mobile internet browser vs accessing a website via UIWebView in a native ios application, for Google Analytics purposes specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code that creates the `UIWebView`, just set a global variable such as `xyz_runningInWebView`:

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.xyz_isRunningInWebView = true")
```

Then query this variable in your Google Analytics code.